# Поиск по дате по каждой строке

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть 2 таблицы

```
--Результат подзапроса (отфильтрованных клиентов)
create table fq (idclient, idblank, datenter) as
    select 1, 1, date'2021-06-03'+0.5 from dual union all  
    select 5, 4, date'2021-03-13'+0.5 from dual union all 
    select 2, 1, date'2021-04-03'+0.5 from dual
```

```
--Вся таблица
create table t (idclient, idblank, datenter) as
    select 5, 13, date'2021-01-14'+0.5 from dual union all
    select 1, 1, date'2021-06-03'+0.5 from dual union all  
    select 1, 5, date'2021-02-13'+0.5 from dual union all 
    select 2, 14, date'2021-06-03'+0.5 from dual union all  
    select 3, 12, date'2021-02-17'+0.5 from dual union all 
    select 4, 9, date'2021-04-03'+0.5 from dual union all  
    select 5, 6, date'2021-01-12'+0.5 from dual union all 
    select 6, 7, date'2021-04-03'+0.5 from dual union all  
    select 5, 4, date'2021-03-13'+0.5 from dual union all 
    select 3, 3, date'2021-04-03'+0.5 from dual union all  
    select 4, 2, date'2021-02-13'+0.5 from dual union all 
    select 2, 1, date'2021-04-03'+0.5 from dual union all
    select 1, 10, date'2021-05-25'+0.5 from dual
```

`Суть задачи` - Узнать, заводилась ранее анкета по клиенту за 3 месяца назад.

`Важно` - Смотреть 3 месяца назад от даты заведения анкеты (индивидуально для каждого клиента). 
 Так же таблица `fq` - это результат подзапроса, по этому при поиске в таблице `t` нельзя учитывать дублирующиеся анкеты.

Я пытался решить следующей логикой :

1. Нужно найти последнюю дату заведённой анкеты по клиенту из запроса `fq`
2. Присоединить таблицу `t` для поиска по ней
3. От последней даты по клиенту, нужно глянуть может были другие анкеты за 3 месяца.

```
select t2.idclient, case when t1.idblank is not null then 1 end as priz_m3
,t1.datenter
from (select 
 idclient, idblank, datenter
from t ) t1
left join (select
  t.idclient, max(t.datenter) as datenter
 from t  join fq on t.idclient=fq.idclient
 group by t.idclient
) t2 on t1.idclient=t2.idclient 
  and t2.datenter between add_months(t1.datenter,-3) and t1.datenter-1
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
IDCLIENT   PRIZ_M3   DATENTER
1             1      25-MAY-21
2            NULL      NULL
5             1      14-JAN-21
5             1      12-JAN-21
```

По факту [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5351577dbfe686cccbeae6f7bd8c5d0)

Comment: Не понял, а почему в ожидаемом результате несколько строчек по одному клиенту и почему не все клиенты(где например клиент с ID3) ?
Вообще я не очнеь понял описание задачи, можете попробовать другими словами сформулировать?

Comment: А что за поле `idblank`, его можно просто игнорировать?

Comment: @ Viktorov. Таблица `fq` - это результат, клиентов прошедших определённые критерии, на `основе этих клиентов` нужно проводить поиск по таблице `t`
В таблице `fq` есть только *1,2,5* клиенты. `idblank` - я планирую использовать в дальнейшем для подсчета количества таких договоров которые попадают в диапазон. В блоке ожидаемого результата 5 клиент имеет 2 договора подходящих по условию. Для этого нужно поле  `idblank`

Comment: А может быть два договора за  одну дату?

Comment: @Viktorov По одному клиенту - нет, а по разным - может

Comment: По 5 клиенту в fq есть строка, которой нет в t, так и должно быть или просто опечатка? В fq datenter  =    '2021-03-13' а в t такой нет.

Comment: Обновил ответ, гляньте. Все еще не то, что вы ищите?)

Comment: @Viktorov Опечатка, месяцем ошибся, поправил. Завтра на свежую голову зайду попробую ваш вариант. Спасибо вам за помощь. О результате отпишусь

Comment: @Akalit Задание так и  осталось до конца не понятным, результат ни одного из ответов не соответствует ожидаемому. Поставил плюс только за образцовое оформление вопроса с данныйми и фиддлом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.idclient
      ,CASE
         WHEN t2.idclient IS NOT NULL THEN
          1
         ELSE
          NULL
       END AS is_enter_earlier -- 1 если заводилась ранее
      ,t2.datenter
  FROM fq t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2
    ON t1.idclient = t2.idclient
   AND t1.datenter != t2.datenter
   AND t2.datenter BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(t1.datenter, -3) AND t1.datenter
 ORDER BY t1.idclient;
```

Comment: Думал, что вы уже покинули метку :) С возвращением!

Comment: @0xdb я периодически наведываюсь, но там уже всегда есть ответы. А тут оп, и нету :)

Answer (score 5):

Сделал бы так:

```
select 
    fq.*, case 
          when add_months (fq.datenter, -3) <= prevFormIssued 
          then 'y' else 'n' end existLessAs3MonthOld
from fq
cross apply (
    select max (datenter) keep (dense_rank first order by datenter desc) prevFormIssued
    from t 
    where t.idclient = fq.idclient 
    and t.datenter < fq.datenter)
```

Результат (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c3cb8c8fdfefc91574e3db3695c8adab)):

```
  IDCLIENT    IDBLANK DATENTER            E
---------- ---------- ------------------- -
         1          1 2021-06-03 12:00:00 y
         5          4 2021-03-13 12:00:00 y
         2          1 2021-04-03 12:00:00 n
```

Ожидаемый результат в вопросе, скорее всего, отличается от описания задачи.